# Web scraping with talend

Tags: web-scraping, talend

I want to extract content from html pages with talend,
how can i do that, is there a specific component ?

it is possible using routines or it is automated by components?

Comment: Hi, there is too little information about what you are trying to do, but I don't think there is a component. But there are java libraries and routines that will allow you to do what you want. There is an article issue on the talend community website on how to manipulate HTML : https://community.talend.com/s/article/Manipulating-HTML-using-Talend-Data-Integration?language=en_US maybe this will help